# How to update part of a ng-view after some async computing

Tags: angularjs, background, promise, pouchdb

I am developing a Single-Page App with Angular 1 / Ionic 1 / PouchDB.

On the home page, I would like to display some synthetic information resulting from a computation on a large set of data, and which may take several seconds (I need to query the PouchDB database through a query promise, and then do some computing).

As a consequence, I would like not to block the home page display, and have it displayed immediately, without this synthetic. Then once the background work is finished, I would like to populate the appropriate `<div>` of the home page.

My question is how to do this...

I have tried various approaches:

- a `resolve` in the UI-Router would not work because it would prevent the home page to display before everything is computed, and this is exactly what I want to avoid
- having a `$scope.syntheticData` variable (empty at the beginning) displayed in the form, and set this variable to the computed value once the computing is finished. But the home page is not updated. Even with `$scope.$apply()`.
- having an event triggered with `$rootScope.$broadcast` when the computing is finished. I listen to this event from the home page controller with `$scope.$on`. I receive the event, then set `$scope.syntheticData` to the received value, but it still does not work. Even with `$scope.$apply`.

I have the feeling this is something very basic, however I find no way to solve it. Many thanks for your help!

---

to answer Harshil Shah's comment, here is one version of my code in the controller to update the scope:

```
  // ctrl function
  $scope.syntheticData = {};

  $scope.$on('updateSynthetic', function() {
    $scope.syntheticData = {}; // trial to make sure Angular sees a change on next line...
    $scope.syntheticData.info1 = synthesis.data.info1;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

`synthesis` is a service retrieving the DB data through a PouchDB query, with a `then()` on the promise to do the computation, and store the results into `synthesis.data.info1` (and also info2, info3, ...)

If I put a console.log in the $on event callback, it appears, so it is called when the event is fired from the service.

Comment: Please paste the code here, let me see how you are trying to update the scope variable when the computation finishes.

Comment: Can't you just set a loaded variable to true once your data is ready and used an ng-if to determine whether the div displays?

Answer (score 0):

Have the function initially return an empty object, then populate that object when the asynchronous operations complete:

```
function expensiveData(params) {
    var emptyObject = {};
    emptyObject.$resolved = false;
    var derivedPromise = asynchronousAPI(params).then(function(data) {
        //Do computation here
        //..
        //Populatate emptyObject
        angular.copy(data, emptyObject);
        emptyObject.$resolved = true;

        //return data for chaining
        return data;
    });

    emptyObject.$promise = $q.when(derivedPromise);

    return emptyObject;
});
```

If the derived promise comes from outside the AngularJS framework, the `$q.when` will make sure that an AngularJS digest cycle gets performed. If not, no harm done.

Then in the client code:

```
$scope.syntheticData = expensiveData(params);

syntheticData.$promise.then(function(data) {
    //DO more stuff here
});
```

HTML

```
<div>{{syntheticData}}</div>
```

On every AngularJS digest cycle, the watcher created by the interpolation `{{ }}` will check the value of `syntheticData` and put it on the DOM when it becomes available.